# Why controller show only the PartialView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, partial-views

The GetUpdateTable function is never called until the first time I enter the page.
It should work that when I press a button the function GetUpdateTable  should be called.

[how should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgKdN.png)

And one of the cell should be colored.
The method to work works correctly but I end up with this view, it would be just the partialview

[how is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWMro.png)

**Hub**

```
[HubName("ShowMatchHub")]
    public class ShowMatchHub : Hub
    {
        [HubMethodName("UpdateTable")]
        public static void UpdateTable()
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ShowMatchHub>();
            if (context.Clients != null)
            {
                context.Clients.All.GetUpdateTable();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetUpdateTable(string Name)
        {
            //string matchName = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[1].Split('=')[1];
            //string url = Request.Url.ToString().Split('?')[1].Split('&')[1];

            Match match = db.Matches.Where(c => c.Name.Equals(Name)).FirstOrDefault();
            match = match.GetMatch(match, db);
            ViewBag.table = match.DrawTable(match);
            return PartialView("_GamePartial", match);
            //return PartialView("_GamePartial");
        }
```

**SignalR Function**

```
$(function () {
            var table = $.connection.ShowMatchHub; 
            
            table.client.GetUpdateTable = function () { 
                var nameMatch = getUrlParameter("Name");
                getAll(nameMatch);
                console.log("chiamato");
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                
                var nameMatch = getUrlParameter("Name");

                getAll(nameMatch);
                table.server.UpdateTable(nameMatch);
            });
        });

        function getUrlParameter(sParam) {...
        };

        function getAll(nameMatch) {
            var model = $('#tableModel');
            console.log(model);
            var urlString = '/Manage/GetUpdateTable' + "?Name=" + nameMatch;
            console.log("c'è");
            $.ajax({
                url: urlString,  
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(result){model.empty().append(result);}  
            });
        }
```